# Not able to see xml schema explorer,when xsd file is being opened

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xsd

when i opened xsd file in vs 2008 iam not able to see xml schema explorer in view ?
any one know how to get the xml Schema explorer...
Plz let me know
Thanks in advance.